# Why isset($_POST{'variable']) return true even if array $_POST is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

that's my code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['mileage']))
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Autos (make,year,mileage) VALUES (:mk, :yr, :mi)'); 
        $stmt->execute(array(':mk' => $_POST['make'],':yr' => $_POST['year'],':mi' => $_POST['mileage']));
        $_POST = Array(); 
    }
```

And I received an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `Automobiles`.`Autos`.`year` at row 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Automobiles/autos.php:15 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Automobiles/autos.php(15): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Automobiles/autos.php on line 15

I don't understand why the code inside if executes, if its not set, why isset returns true?

Comment: So is `year` a datetime column, but you pass an integer like `2010` to it?

Comment: Can you show us var_dump of post? Maybe the value is a string?

Comment: The var_dump is: array(3) { ["make"]=> string(0) "" ["year"]=> string(0) "" ["mileage"]=> string(0) "" }, but that is still empty strings, I am noob in php, so its confusing for me

Comment: `isset("")` returns true, because empty string is not `null`

Comment: They are empty, but they are set! They are just empty string.

Comment: Ahh, okey, I added checking if it is not equal true, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should validate year param before inserting and use `empty` for checking

```
    function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
    {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        // The Y ( 4 digits year ) returns TRUE for any integer with any number of digits so changing the comparison from == to === fixes the issue.
        return $d && $d->format($format) === $date;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['make']) && !empty($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['mileage']) && validateDate($_POST['year']))
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Autos (make,year,mileage) VALUES (:mk, :yr, :mi)'); 
        $stmt->execute(array(':mk' => $_POST['make'],':yr' => $_POST['year'],':mi' => $_POST['mileage']));
        $_POST = Array(); 
    }
```